# How to add type-safety to attributes in Sequelize queries

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

From the docs at: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#specifying-attributes-for-select-queries

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: ['foo', 'bar']
});
```

This is horrible as it doesn't allow for one of the main advantages of an ORM: type-safety.

What I'd instead want to be able to do is something like:

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: [Model.foo, Model.bar]
});
```

Other ORMs support this. Prisma for example and Entity Framework (obviously, being .Net).

Is there any way to achieve something similar with Sequelize? Perhaps some additional library even?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm asking myself the same question. This can't be the way it should be done.